# Get-DnsClientCache alters output when piped to Select-Object

Tags: powershell

Get-DNSClientCache displays string values but when when piped to Select they are displayed as integers. How can this be overcome to keep the values outputted as strings Note: RecordType and Status.
Trying to avoid complex Case or IF Else logic.

[image: Get-DnsCleintCache]

[image: Get-DnsClientCache | Select]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get-dnsclientcache` is part of the DnsClient module, and this ships with a number of custom formatters that are used for default output, and it's these custom formatters that are responsible for translating numbers to strings. Once you pipe the output through some other cmdlet, you lose the default formatting rules.

**Background**: when a cmdlet is ran without any piping, PowerShell sends the output through the `out-default` cmdlet behind the scenes, and there are rules that define how different types of output are formatted. These are typically defined in `.ps1xml` files, and PowerShell ships with a default set. Additionally, modules can supply their own `ps1xml` files with their own formatting rules, and that's what's happening with DnsClient.

The DnsClient module is installed on Windows at `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\DnsClient`, and if you take a look in that folder, you'll see a number of `.ps1xml` files. The one containing the custom rules for `Get-DnsClientCache` is `DnsConfig.Format.ps1xml`, and if you scroll down the file you'll come across this:

[image: Snippet from DnsClient formatting rules]

If you scroll back up the file, you'll see that this section relates to the type `MSFT_DnsClientCache`, which is the default type that `Get-DnsClientCache` spits out (you can see this piping to `get-member`). So in short, the mapping of numbers to strings is hard-coded via script-blocks in this formatting file that's used by `out-default`.

When you pipe the output of a cmdlet through `select-object`, the output object of select-object is not the same as the original cmdlet (on my machine `get-member` reports it as CimInstance), so it doesn't get the specific MSFT_DnsClientCache formatting.

So in answer to *How can this be overcome to keep the values outputted as strings*, you'll need to map the numbers to strings manually in your own script. Which, yes, is less than ideal. But hopefully this provides some information on how you can find out what those mappings are.

For further reading, information about the `.ps1xml` file format can be found on MSDN at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml?view=powershell-7.3

Comment: You da man Chris. Thank you. Yes , less than ideal